# Using j_security_check for authentication, but not authorization (in Websphere)

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, websphere

Is there a way to force my Java EE application to use j_security_check for authentication, but not authorization?  I want to do authentication through a Standalone LDAP Repository, but I want to do programmatic authorization in my application.

Specifically, I do not want to do any configuration around Authorization (user role mapping to groups) within the Websphere Application Server admin console.

For example:

1. User logs in with 'user1' and password 'password1' which are correct
2. Websphere finds this person in LDAP, knows they are who they say they are (Authentication)
3. I check from a file on the file system if this user is authorized or not (Authorization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using Spring Security for this. We have implemented this exact pattern in WebSphere. The trick is to use the pre-authentication mechanism that Spring Security provides and then define only the authorization rules in the configuration.

```
<http>
  <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
  <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthenticationFilter"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/j_security_check" filters="none"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/ibm_security_logout" filters="none"/>
  <!-- put authorization intercept-url elements here... -->
</http>
```

You have to define some other beans as well, such as the pre-authenticated filter and a custom entry point, but that's documented here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html

Comment: I figured Spring Security was the way to go, but I just could not find the right entry point into the documentation.  Thanks for the references!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need the example filled out a bit more as you work through it (or you can edit the answer, of course). Like I said, there are some peripheral things that you have to do (both to the Spring configuration) and the web.xml file (for the Java EE authentication piece).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Spring Security. The concepts of authentication and authorisation are split.

Authentication is handled by an `AuthenticationProvider` (an [`LdapAuthenticationProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/LdapAuthenticationProvider.html) implementation is part of spring). The authentication provider delegates to fetch details of the user, which includes a list of `GrantedAuthority` objects which can represent a user's permissions.

`LdapAuthenticationProvider` by default attempts to get granted authorities from the directory, so you will need to provider your own `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` implementation which loads from the file system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I gave the win to the other post for slightly more comprehensive references.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE Security can be split as well.  It depends on your container's implementation however.
Since you mention websphere [this document](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html) might be of interest.