# Websphere Application Server 8.5. Load roles by custom code on Federated repository

Tags: ldap, websphere

I'm uses WAS with security realm Federated repository.
In federated repository configured repository with type LDAP:CUSTOM. It's worked fine and I can authenticate in my web application via LDAP.

But how can I load roles (authorization) for my web application from custom database/from static list by username? (not from LDAP)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using j\_security\_check for authentication, but not authorization (in Websphere)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739319/using-j-security-check-for-authentication-but-not-authorization-in-websphere)

Comment: If you are using custom LDAP, then typical way is just to create groups in ldap that are matching your roles and then add users to these groups. In such a way you will be able to map roles define in your application/web.xml to the ldap gropus via binding file, admin console or wsadmin script.